# pintar datos enviados desde otro componente

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Estoy tratando de enviar un objeto que contiene un array de objetos desde un componente, que funciona como un formulario a otro componente que pintaría una tabla con dichos datos de mis objetos. Para ello estoy usando vue js 3 y option API ya que con composition API me pasaba lo mismo y traté de hacerlo por esta vía pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

La API está construida con Laravel 9 y se hace una consulta a la DB de esta manera:

```
return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('cp', '=', $value)->get());
```

Esto me devuelve 160 arrays con el objeto en su interior, de esta manera:

```
(160) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0:{id: 895, name: 'Aguilera Muriel Fatimas', address: 'CALLE CALLEJAS, 8', province: 'GRANADA', city: 'PURULLENA', …}
```

Este resultado, lo asigno a una variable reactiva:

```
data() {
  return {
    dataRegisters: ref([]),
```

y en mi componente tabla, tengo definida la propiedad registers y la intento mostrar en el template:

```
export default {
        name: "nAsignedCalls",        
        props: {
            registers: [Array, Object],
            required: true,
            default: {
                        "address": "CALLE CALLEJAS, 8",
                        "city": "PURULLENA",
                        "cp": "18519",
                        "created_at": null,
                        "id": 895,
                        "mobile_phone": null,
                        "name": "Aguilera Muriel Fatimas",
                        "phone": "958.690.236",
                        "province": "GRANADA",
                        "source":"",
                        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T07:35:30.000000Z"
                    }

        },
        computed: {
            totalRegisters() {
                console.log(this.registers)
                return this.registers;
            }
        },
        watch: {
            registers: function (newValue, oldValue){
                console.log("newValue " + newValue)
            }
        }
    }

{{ (registers) ? registers : 'nada' }}
```

Para enviar los datos a mi componente tabla, estoy usando una función que captura los valores de mis inputs de mi formulario y cuando hago click en el botón llamo a esta función:

```
methods: {
            async fetchData() {
                var address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    this.param_search['parameter'] = 'address'
                    this.param_search['value'] = address
                }

                var city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    this.param_search["parameter"] = "city";
                    this.param_search["value"] = city;
                }

                var cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    this.param_search["parameter"] = "cp";
                    this.param_search["value"] = cp
                }

                try {
                    const resp = await axios.get(`/api/listingApi/getRegister/${this.param_search["parameter"]}/${this.param_search["value"]}`)
                    this.dataRegisters.value = resp.data.data

                    console.log(this.dataRegisters.value)

                    /*const nAsignedCalls = this.$refs.nAsignedCalls;
                    nAsignedCalls.setData(this.registers)*/

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
```

En el `console.log()` veo perfectamente los datos de mi array de objetos pero no consigo hacerlos llegar a mi componente tabla que para esto, estoy usando:

```
<nAsignedCalls :registers="dataRegisters"></nAsignedCalls>
```

No consigo hacer que mis datos llegen a mi componente tabla, siempre me muestra en la vista esto:

```
[]
```

Y en el console puedo ver perfectamente el contenido de mi variable referenciada: `console.log(this.dataRegisters.value)`

Alguien por favor, podría echarme una mano y decirme que estoy haciendo mal¿? Gracias de antemano.